# When to use related table vs constant for drop down or multi-select fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a number of drop down fields some with 2, 4, 10, and 50 choices.  This are has_one and belongs_to relationships.  I also have a few many to many relationships.

Currently, I am using a Module with CONSTANTs to populate my dropdown.

```
SOFTWARE = [ "Windows, "OSX", "iOS", "Word", "Excel"]
```

I store the values as strings, or if its a has_many type of relationships, I store it as a Postgres array.

I was advised that I should be using related tables, with belongs_to and has_one relationships for data integrity and scaling.

How does using related tables help with scalings and data integrity?  When would you advise a CONSTANT be used and when should a related table be used?

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on your choice. I have done situations where I've used a built-in array to check for validations on the type. For example,

```rb
CITIES = ['Toronto', 'Vancouver', 'New York'].freeze
validates :city, presence: true, inclusion: { in: CITIES }
```

I would use a table when you realize there are any other extra details about your enum types. In this situation, I wouldn't use a table for this scenario.

What you could do is use Postgres Enums. They can leverage and help keep your data consistent. Rails has some documentation about this too.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#enumerated-types

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdown value exceeds more than 5 or at some point new values might be added in to the dropdown, it is better to use `related tables`. Also if there might be `changes` to the dropdown values made `frequently` then it is easy to make in the `related table`.

`has_one` - one table with the dropdown values and the reference column in main table
`many_to_many` - one table with the dropdown values. Intermediate table which refers to the dropdown table and the main table.
'https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html'

`Constants/enum`-
If dropdown values is less, for example: gender("male","female","other") in such cases `enum` can be used , as at any scenario new values will not be added to the dropdown. 
'https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html'

Comment: If changes are not made frequently, what is the real advantage? How does it improve scaling or data integrity?

Comment: With respect to scaling - you might add multiple values or you might expand the scope of the drop down values, in both cases if a related table is present it is easy. And with integrity - instead of using the values directly , it is better to use reference ids or keys, which can be achieved by using either enum or related tables